# angularjs ng-repeat drop down menu from json nested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, drop-down-menu

I have the following example.json file:

```
[
  {
    "interests": [
      {
        "item": "art"
      },
      {
        "item": "literature"
      },
      {
        "item": "history"
      },
      {
        "item": "science"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "experience": [
      {
        "year": "novice"
      },
      {
        "year": "experienced"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and in my view controller, I read the file like this:

```
app.controller('ProfileCtrl', ["$scope", "$state", "$http",
    function ($scope, $state, $http) {

    $http.get('files/example.json').success(function (data)
        {
            $scope.myjsonobj= data;
        });
```

and in my html view, I am injecting the values like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
...
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="user.favs">
       <option ng-repeat="p in interests.myjsonobj" value="{{p.item}}">{{p.item}}</option>
    </select>
```

### question:

How can I show only the list of values of "interests" in my dropdown menu? How can I access the nested json array in angularjs?
my current setup is not working.

Comment: You can set `$scope.myjsonobj` to `data.interests` instead of to the entire JSON reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming 'interests' is your controller shortname.

you can use:

```
<option ng-repeat="p in myjsonobj[0].interests" value="{{p.item}}">{{p.item}}</option>
```

Ideally, you should loop the data object to find the index with the 'interests' key vs hardcoding [0].

update: removed "interests." from the repeat.  doesn't seem like you have the ctrl shortname binding.

Comment: what do you mean by controller shortname? I updated my controller name in my question, trying to avoid name confusions.

Comment: ng-controller="YourControllerName as interests"

this binds methods and properties of your controller to "interests".  with that in the html, you access scope variable via interests.scopeVariable.

Comment: if you don't have setup, then just change it to this:
<option ng-repeat="p in myjsonobj[0]" value="{{p.item}}">{{p.item}}</option>

Comment: could you please look at my updated question and provide an adapted answer please. I am confused now with different terminologies.

Comment: can you show me the html element where you have the ng-controller binded?
e.g.

<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl...">

Comment: i updated the question added the controller binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an angular guy. But with my javascript knowledge it seems to me that the

"interests.myjsonobj"

should be

"myjsonobj.interests"